# Different monitor/resolution, different layout

Tags: html, navbar, resolution, fixed

I have this logo on the website, which is positioned in the center between the navbar menus.

Here's a picture:

[Logo Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgThm.png)

The problem is that the logo moves when I switch to a different monitor or resolution. Am I doing something wrong? How do I make it fixed between different resolutions.

Here's the html code:

```html
<main class="site-main">
 <center><img src="img/corelogo.png" alt="Post" height="180" width="180" style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 570px; margin: 0 auto;"></center>
        <section class="hero_area">
            <div class="hero_content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
                            <h1>TeamSpan Global Solutions</h1>
                            <h2>Your partner in building satellite workforce teams.</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all center tag has been deprecated. Secondly, you're positioning it 570px left of the right edge of the first positioned (not static) ancestor element. I can't see what styles are applied to your classes so I can't see what that would be. But it would definitely move around based on resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already heard about Responsive Design? 
Look, you have to post your css too! Can you write it on jsfiddle?

Some examples:

```
https:// codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/dGPZvR (remove space)
https://www.bootply.com/mQh8DyRfWY
https:// codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/Fkwys (remove space)
```